# fclose doesn't seem to be working in C

Tags: c, shell, unix, file-io, memory-leaks

```
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(file != NULL){
        char command[MAX_BUFFER];
        while(fgets(command, MAX_BUFFER, file) != NULL){ //read line
            //operations
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    else write(fileno(stderr), ERROR_MESSAGE, strlen(ERROR_MESSAGE));
```

I'm working on a pretty basic UNIX shell implementation that reads and executes line by line from a file.  From the above code, I'm trying to figure out why `fclose()` might fail since valgrind seems to be telling me that I've left this file descriptor open.

Am I correct in assuming that the "still reachable" 568 bytes in the leak summary refer to a failed `fclose()` somehow?

```
==25428== FILE DESCRIPTORS: 4 open at exit.
==25428== Open file descriptor 3: test
==25428==    at 0x4F186B0: __open_nocancel (syscall-template.S:82)
==25428==    by 0x4EAC628: _IO_file_fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:233)
==25428==    by 0x4EA1265: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:93)
==25428==    by 0x400C0C: main (in /home/Desktop/sh)
==25428== 
==25428== Open file descriptor 2: /dev/pts/0
==25428==    <inherited from parent>
==25428== 
==25428== Open file descriptor 1: /dev/pts/0
==25428==    <inherited from parent>
==25428== 
==25428== Open file descriptor 0: /dev/pts/0
==25428==    <inherited from parent>
==25428== 
==25428== LEAK SUMMARY:
==25428==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25428==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25428==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25428==    still reachable: 568 bytes in 1 blocks
==25428==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Comment: fclose() has a return value.  Check it.  If it failed then you probably smashed the stack.

Comment: compile with ``-g`` flag will be helpful.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you use `write(fileno(stderr), ERROR_MESSAGE, strlen(ERROR_MESSAGE))` rather than `fputs(ERROR_MESSAGE, stderr)`?

Comment: Also, why `fileno(stderr)` instead of `STDERR_FILENO`?  Unless you are `freopen`-ing stderr somewhere, this will just confuse maintainers.

Comment: @KeithThompson For this implementation, I'll be forking some processes and if I recall correctly, fputs would internally buffer the string similar to printf

Comment: Wouldn't `fflush(stdout)` solve that?

Comment: @KeithThompson Yeah.. but I'd rather keep things as one-liners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your visible code looks ok.
But to answer your question: likely, but the problem is somewhere else ;-)

To debug your program, comment out 'operations', so you have an empty loop.
Does valgrind still complain ?

No: the problem very likely lies within the code you named 'operations'.

Remove the comments and compile with debugging symbols on (-g) and use valgrind with these options:
valgrind --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --track-origins=yes yourprogram

Yes: (very unlikely) something else got smashed, try to valgrind with more commented code.

To find bugs at compile time, use the compiler's flags (e.g. gcc has -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wformat=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 and more).

And make use of static analysers e.g. llvm/clang (compile with clang --analyze yourprogram.c)

Answer (score 1):

Right, check the return value, also stick in a perror to get a brief explanation.  If you want confirmation that it's still open try lsof, but you'll probably need to grep it for the program name or pid since there may be dozens.

Answer (score 0):

@rockdaboot's suggestion to comment out my operations showed I'm still losing the memory but at least I know its not from fclose... Thanks for the tips, everyone!  Back to debugging!